# WebRTC from Firefox to Android crashes

Tags: android, firefox, webrtc

I am using WebRTC on Android to communicate with various other browsers.  This works fine for communication with Microsoft Edge, Chrome, and Safari.  When I try to set up a peer connection between Android and Firefox, the offer received from Firefox causes a crash when Android tries to set the remote description.

```
03-27 19:05:25.426  3495  3495 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Android/mybuild/mybuild:11/RQ3A.211001.001/eng.ecomma.20240110.205526:userdebug/dev-keys'
03-27 19:05:25.426  3495  3495 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
03-27 19:05:25.426  3495  3495 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
03-27 19:05:25.427  3495  3495 F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2024-03-27 19:05:25+0000
03-27 19:05:25.427  3495  3495 F DEBUG   : pid: 3331, tid: 3486, name: worker_thread -  >>> my.package <<<
03-27 19:05:25.427  3495  3495 F DEBUG   : uid: 10112
03-27 19:05:25.427  3495  3495 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
03-27 19:05:25.428  3495  3495 F DEBUG   : Abort message: '../../../home/kanat/webrtc/src/buildtools/third_party/libc++/trunk/include/vector:571: assertion !empty() failed: front() called on an empty vector'
03-27 19:05:25.428  3495  3495 F DEBUG   :     x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000000000000d9e  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000007d0760e3c0
03-27 19:05:25.428  3495  3495 F DEBUG   :     x4  fefefefeff716e73  x5  fefefefeff716e73  x6  fefefefeff716e73  x7  7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
03-27 19:05:25.428  3495  3495 F DEBUG   :     x8  00000000000000f0  x9  0000007f2bcf5800  x10 ffffff80fffffbdf  x11 0000000000000001
03-27 19:05:25.428  3495  3495 F DEBUG   :     x12 0000007f2f436020  x13 000000007fffffff  x14 00000000001c9be0  x15 0000000761381d5f
03-27 19:05:25.428  3495  3495 F DEBUG   :     x16 0000007f2bd8ec88  x17 0000007f2bd70490  x18 0000007c99bc6000  x19 00000000000000ac
03-27 19:05:25.428  3495  3495 F DEBUG   :     x20 0000000000000d03  x21 00000000000000b2  x22 0000000000000d9e  x23 00000000ffffffff
03-27 19:05:25.428  3495  3495 F DEBUG   :     x24 b400007df8cca1d0  x25 0000007d0760f000  x26 b400007d38d04898  x27 b400007e18cd06d0
03-27 19:05:25.428  3495  3495 F DEBUG   :     x28 0000007d07947f91  x29 0000007d0760e440
03-27 19:05:25.428  3495  3495 F DEBUG   :     lr  0000007f2bd23544  sp  0000007d0760e3a0  pc  0000007f2bd23574  pst 0000000000000000
03-27 19:05:25.429  3495  3495 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
03-27 19:05:25.430  3495  3495 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 000000000004e574  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+180) (BuildId: eea04dcb79f7c0732c4186dc99769352)
```

I have tried multiple different builds of the native WebRTC library on Android.  This only occurs when using Firefox.  The specific version of Firefox is 124.0.1.

I turned on verbose logging for WebRTC on Android and the last line that prints before the crash is

```
[onLogMessage] label: webrtc_video_engine.cc, message: (line 2833): AddRecvStream: {id:Zf3iOnP6;ssrcs:[1701703699];ssrc_groups:;cname:{4fe1736b-1ba1-400f-8341-2a05850eed4f};stream_ids:default;}
```

This is interesting because it shouldn't be expecting to receive any streams as the Android side is only streaming video to the Firefox side and nothing in reverse.

Edit:
I've tried this library: https://github.com/GetStream/webrtc-android
And this library: https://github.com/rno/WebRTC

Comment: use the following library https://github.com/rno/WebRTC to add the webrtc reference,. make sure that you init the remotevideoview only once and on the GUI using runOnUiThread. on the gotRemoteStream addtarget also on the GUI (runOnUiThread)

Comment: I've tried that library with the same result.  It never gets far enough to run anything with the remotevideoview because it is failing setting the remote description to set up the peer connection.

Comment: try using Plan_B "rtcConfig.sdpSemantics = PeerConnection.SdpSemantics.PLAN_B;
            rtcConfig.candidateNetworkPolicy = PeerConnection.CandidateNetworkPolicy.ALL;"

Comment: and force software encoder "VideoEncoderFactory videoEncoderFactory = new SoftwareVideoEncoderFactory();
                    VideoDecoderFactory videoDecoderFactory = new SoftwareVideoDecoderFactory();
                    peerConnectionFactory = PeerConnectionFactory.builder()
                            .setOptions(options)
                            .setVideoEncoderFactory(videoEncoderFactory)
                            .setVideoDecoderFactory(videoDecoderFactory)
                            .createPeerConnectionFactory();"

Comment: A video decoder isn't necessary as I'm not expecting video on the Android end.  I'm streaming from Android to Firefox.  I have the video encoder set up as you have described above already.

PLAN_B is marked as deprecated. I'm using UNIFIED_PLAN.  I tried adding the candidateNetworkPolicy but it did not change the outcome.  I'm suspect of what is happening on the Firefox side but it's the same code that I'm running in all other browsers.